# Blue Prism Application Modeller best practice

Tags: blueprism

When working with a bigger application (a ERP system such as SAP or something similar). What is the best practice when setting up the Application Modeller?

Some like to have a Basic Action object that contains the Application Modellerer. The rest of the objects then inherit that (Using "Share the Application Model of another object")

But what if the plan is to ramp up and have several developers using this application? Because right now, only a single developer can edit in the Application Modeller at a time. Is it better separate the Application Modeller for each window?

Answer (score 1):

Blue Prism has official guidance on this in their Object Design Guide document, available on the Blue Prism Portal.

> ### 4.5 When is a multi-object design appropriate?
>
> - All projects where it is possible that the business objects will end up in production,
>     regardless of the size of the initial development team.
> - Any proof of concept project whereby multiple developers are required to develop
>     against an individual application.

More directly to your question is their guidance surrounding the use of Shared Application Models within the same document. In a nutshell, the use of Shared Application Models is primarily geared toward applications that may not, for one reason or another, be conducive for separate Attach functionality in the separate objects.

> ### 6. Shared Application Models
>
> Occasionally, you may encounter applications where it is not possible
>   to Attach to the target application, making the recommended
>   multi-object design problematic. Fortunately, v5 of Blue Prism
>   introduced the concept of a shared application model to enable a
>   multi-object design approach in such scenarios. When using a shared
>   application model, all the elements are managed within a single object
>   (typically the object that launches the application) and accessed by
>   the other objects. In this scenario, there is no requirement for the
>   other objects to Attach to the target application.